# Navbar font family change only on category page

Tags: wordpress, elementor

i have problem on my wordpress Elementor theme,

I change font family of navbar text, is work on all website but when i go on category product page font don't load

[Normal page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwS6E.png)

On category page

[On categorie page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZYxX.png)

Comment: A link to the website is required to inspect and find the root cause.

Comment: Share website URL @P2P

Comment: @SavanDholu this is the link

Comment: @P2P Where is the website link?

Comment: @SavanDholu 31-degres.fr

Comment: @VinayJain 31-degres.fr

Comment: It's in maintenance mode

Comment: @VinayJain it's online